# Retornar Lista do Controller para a View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um `controller` onde valido as informações do `ModelState`, armazeno os erros em uma lista.

*Gostaria de pegar essa lista e retornar para minha view.* Mas sou iniciante e não estou conseguindo entender como posso fazer isso, pois poderia usar o `ValidationSummary` para listar? ou usar uma `partial` para o retorno dentro da `view`?

Meu controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(ClienteViewModel viewmodel)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Set<Pessoa>().Add(viewmodel.Pessoa);

        if (viewmodel.Cliente.TipoPessoa.Equals(Models.Enum.TipoPessoa.Juridica))
        {
            // db.Set<PessoaJuridica>().Add(viewmodel.PessoaJuridica);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Set<PessoaFisica>().Add(viewmodel.PessoaFisica);
        }

        db.Cliente.Add(viewmodel.Cliente);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {   /*Lista que quero retornar para minha view*/ 
        var ListaErros = new List<string>();
        foreach (var values in ModelState.Values)
        {
            foreach (var erros in values.Errors)
            {
                ListaErros.Add(erros.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }

    }
    return View(viewmodel);
}
```

`View`:

```
@model Sistema.ViewModels.ClienteViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Cliente</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cliente.TipoPessoa, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Cliente.TipoPessoa, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cliente.TipoPessoa, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para este caso (Listar erros), [**ValidationSummary**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary(v=vs.110).aspx) é a melhor opção.

Para usa-lo, na sua View apenas adicione isso onde o Sumário de erros deverá aparecer:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

No seu código é possível notar que você já tem o *ValidationSummary* então possívelmente sua dúvida está em como adicionar itens a ele. Para isso, no seu Controller, sempre que um erro ocorre, adicione ao summary usando [`ModelState.AddModelError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror(v=vs.118).aspx). Exemplo:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) 
{ 
    if(x == y //Uma condição qualquer)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "O x é igual a y!");

        return View(suaView);
    }
}
```

### Outras opções para comunicar Controller > View

Todo conteúdo abaixo estou colocando devido as suas dúvidas sobre como enviar informação da Controller para a View e devido a pergunta que está no título:

> Retornar Lista do Controller para a View

Você pode usar o [**TempData**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata(v=vs.118).aspx), [**ViewBag**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag(v=vs.118).aspx) ou [**ViewData**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary(v=vs.100).aspx). De forma resumida, a diferença entre eles é que o *TempData* tem um tempo de duração maior, enquanto *ViewBag* e *ViewData* são semelhantes e o tempo de vida desses dois é, basicamente, o de envio da *Controller* para a *View*, após isso já passa a ser nula.

#### Exemplo com TempData

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var ListaErros = new List<string>();
    ListaErros.Add("Erro 1");
    ListaErros.Add("Erro 2");

    TempData["erros"] = ListaErros;

    return View();
}
```

Na sua **View**:

```
@{
    foreach(string erro in TempData["erros"]  as List<string>)
    {
        Html.TextBox(erro);
    }
}
```

---

#### Exemplo com ViewBag

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var ListaErros = new List<string>();
    ListaErros.Add("Erro 1");
    ListaErros.Add("Erro 2");

    ViewBag.ListaErros= ListaErros;

    return View();
}
```

Na sua **View**:

```
@{
    foreach (string erro in ViewBag.ListaErros)
    {
        Html.TextBox(erro);
    }
}
```

---

#### Exemplo com ViewData

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var ListaErros = new List<string>();
    ListaErros.Add("Erro 1");
    ListaErros.Add("Erro 2");

    ViewData["erros"] = ListaErros;

    return View();
}
```

Na sua **View**:

```
@{
    foreach(string erro in ViewData["erros"]  as List<string>)
    {
        Html.TextBox(erro);
    }
}
```

Outra diferença que pode notar nos exemplos é que o `TempData` e `ViewData` requer um `TypeCasting` (`TempData["erros"]  as List<string>`, por exemplo) enquanto para o `ViewBag` não é necessário.